# querySelector: what is the return type?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, selectors-api

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) documentation, `querySelector` returns an `Element`. However, the return value is generally richer than that.

For example if I select an `img` element, I really get a `HTMLImageElement` which, according to the documentation, is part of this hierarchy:

```
EventTarget ← Node ← Element ← HTMLElement ← HTMLImageElement
```

My understanding of inheritance is that objects have access to properties further down the chain, but not further up.

Does this imply that `querySelector` doesn’t actually return an `Element`, but rather one of a number of objects which extend `Element`?

Comment: Can I understand the use-case ? Could this be an XYProblem? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Congratulation, you've discovered something called polymorphism.

Comment: It returns a `HTMLImageElement`, or whatever querySelector finds, but the nice thing about a dynamic language, the return type can also be dynamic, static languages would require you to type-cast here,.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this imply that querySelector doesn’t actually return an Element, but rather one of a number of objects which extend Element?

Any object which is a subclass of Element is still an Element. It is just something more specific as well.

Answer (score 0):

When a document indicates that a specific interface (`Element`) is returned, it logically means that everything that implements that interface (`HTMLImageElement`) is also counted, otherwise they'd have to list all the subclasses in particular which would've been redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLImageElement` actually **implements** Element, instead of *extending* it, and retains all properties of `HTMLElement`, which implements all properties of `Element`.

Any `instanceof` checks on the objects returned by `querySelector` is truthy for `Element`, except when it's null. So, for querySelector it doesn't matter that the prototype of the returned element is of type `HTMLImageElement`, as long as the element is implements all properties of `Element` and provides a truthy check for 
`instanceof Element`.

The element returned by querySelector is guaranteed to have all the properties of `Element` or would be null, if you want to use other specialized properties, you'd have to do your own `instanceof` checks.